# How can I trim whitespace from request parameters in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, data-binding, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm struggling to believe that my need to trim leading and trailing whitespace from request parameters is not a common requirement, and yet I can't seem to find anyone who has a good answer to solving it.

Surely there is some simple way to configure, say, the Spring `WebDataBinder` to trim all whitespace from parameter values before mapping them to a target object?

I'd be really keen to know how other people have tackled this.

Answer (score 6):

You can try registering a custom `PropertyEditor` in the `WebDataBinder`

```
 registerCustomEditor(String.class, propertyEditor)
```

Either create one or use the [`StringTrimmerEditor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringTrimmerEditor.html), and instantiate it with a set of whitespaces.