# Spring StringTrimmerEditor not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As I read here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html#portlet-ann-webdatabinder

And as I saw in some other question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323284/how-can-i-trim-whitespace-from-request-parameters-in-spring-mvc), I'm registering a StringTrimmerEditor in my controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{


    @InitBinder
     public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) 
     {
       binder.registerCustomEditor(StringTrimmerEditor.class,new  StringTrimmerEditor(false));
     }
```

It compiles and runs, but does not work, it doesn't trim the data. I don't know what am I missing. Anyone?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor%29) to the rescue:

> public void registerCustomEditor(Class requiredType,
>                                    PropertyEditor propertyEditor)
>
> ```
> Description copied from interface: PropertyEditorRegistry
> Register the given custom property editor for all properties of the given type.
>
> Specified by:
>     registerCustomEditor in interface PropertyEditorRegistry
>
> Parameters:
>     requiredType - the type of the property
>     propertyEditor - the editor to register
> ```

The class should not be the class of the editor.It should be the type of the fields on which you want the editor to apply: `String.class`

Comment: I have to admit I was lazy yesterday at that late time at night, so instead of researching I rather asked here, expecting to have an answer today in the morning.